# Transmission lines

Tags: transmission-line

I have a little confusion about power transmission lines. In my home town, there are 4 conductors parallel to each other coming down from the main road on steel poles. Then, on every street, two conductors are distributing power to each home. Now, the four condctors which are coming down from the road — are these are called bundled condutors (no spacers are present between them)? Are they a 3 phase 4 wire system? And also explain the conductors that are distributing power on the streets.

Comment: Please add the country where you saw these electrical wires. A photo, drawing or more detailled explanation of the wires (grouping/connections) and electricity pylons would also help.

Answer (score 1):

They are almost certainly not bundled conductors (see [Electrotechnik](http://www.electrotechnik.net/2011/02/bundled-conductors-in-tranmission-lines.html)).  Those are only used on high voltage transmission lines.

They are very likely to be a 3-phase 4-wire system, with three phase (live, hot) conductors and one shared neutral.  Premises that only need a single-phase supply will get a tap off one phase and the neutral.